# LUIS Programmatic API 2 - Training status becomes "InProgress" for infinite time

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am trying to train my App with the following API.

Visit https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c45

The API gets executed successfully but after that, the app's training status remains **InProgress** for infinite time.

Status changes to **Trained** only if I train the app manually from LUIS's web console.

Am I missing any step or is it a platform bug?

Comment: Please share your code with us, so we can be of more help.

Comment: Well, I am just trying the APIs with Postman currently.

Comment: Please share your App Id so that we can look into it.

Comment: @JyoFanidam Here is my app id
8f14806d-192f-4003-a0ac-822d85c9afee

Answer (score 0):

Application provided was deleted so we couldn't repro the issue.

The API should be used in the following steps:

1. POST - To start the training: [https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/{versionId}/train](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c45)
2. GET - To get the training status: [https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/{versionId}/train](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c46)

Repeat this call till all training status are successful or upto-date.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Actually, my issue was that I was trying to train an app which had intents without utterances.
Once I added at least one utterance to each intent, it worked perfectly.